# A conjecture on numbers coprime to its Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I was investigating the natural numbers $n$ such that $\gcd(n,\phi(n)) = 1$ where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function. Clearly $\phi(n)$ is even for $n > 2$ hence $\gcd(n,\phi(n)) \ge 2$ if $n$ is even. Again if $n = p$ is an odd prime then $\phi(p) = p-1$ which is trivially co-prime to $p$. Hence all non-trivial $n$ such that $\gcd(n,\phi(n)) = 1$ must be odd composites. Apart from $1$ and the trivial set of primes, the sequence of composite numbers with this property are $15, 33, 35,51,65,69,77, 85,87, 91, 95, \ldots$ I observed the following.

> **Conjecture**: If $n$ is an odd composite number such that $\gcd(n,\phi(n)) = 1$ then the number of divisors of $n$ is a perfect
>   power of $2$.

Can this be proved or disproved?

Related question: [How many numbers $n$ are there such that $\gcd(n,\phi(n)) = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365153/how-many-numbers-n-are-there-such-that-gcdn-phin-1)

Comment: Emm! As you observed numbers with such property are $15,33,35,51,65,69,77,85,87,91,95$, and so on. We can see that all of these numbers are basically of the form $pq$ for some prime $p$ and $q$ and all these have exactly 4 divisors. Not sure if that helps, but yeah some observation :)

Comment: @crskhr This is not true in general. $255$ is the smallest number with this property which has more than $8$ divisors.

Comment: No! You misunderstood me. $255=pqr$ which again is product of $3$ primes. What i was trying to hint at is the following: If such a $n$ exists, then $n$ is the product of distinct primes, each with exponent 1.

Comment: Hmm, why is $39=3 \cdot 13$ **not** in the list? Is this known? P.S.: the miraculous OEIS: http://oeis.org/A050384

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$, then $n$ must be square-free.

To see this, assume $p^2|n$ for some prime $p$. Then $p|\phi(n)$, and so $p|\gcd(n,\phi(n))$.

If $n=p_1\cdots p_m$ where $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ are distinct primes, then the divisors of $n$ are all numbers formed by the product of a subset of these, and there are $2^m$ such subset (including the whole set which results in $n$ itself, and the empty set which gives 1).